# Water temperature or the water temperature

Tags: word-choice

Should I use "the" before "water"?
"A hurricane occurs where the water temperature is high."

Comment: Hurricanes occur where surface-water temperature is high. A hurricane occurs when surface-water temperature is high. You'd say "the" beforehand when talking about a specific surface-water temperature, meaning the temperature of specific surface water.

Comment: You might say, for example, "Hurricanes in the Gulf of Mexico occur where *the* surface-water temperature is high." You're referring specifically about the temperature of the various surface waters of the Gulf of Mexico, specifically those where the surface-water temperature is high, so "the" is called for. When speaking nonspecifically but generally, "the" is not called for.

Comment: Is it compulsory to use "surface-water" and not just "water"?